# How to Store user login credential in Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to store the username and password of users locally. i have searched a lot can't find a working solution for Xamarin.forms.I have seen this official site that recommend to use Xamarin.Auth to store in keychain but the tutorial in on platforms specific which i dont know how to convert to Xamarin.Forms.

A little bit help on how to make this to work in Xamarin.Form is very much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check on this [link](http://www.joesauve.com/using-xamarin-auth-with-xamarin-forms/) for how to use Xamarin.Auth in Xamarin.Forms.
One more option i would consider is using [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) which can be used to store the data with same level of security & how to integrate it in Xamarin.Forms check on this [link](http://blog.masterdevs.com/xf-day-8/)

Answer (score 3):

I have been using the [SecureStorage plugin](https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage) which saves these kinds of settings in the platforms secure storage from the shared code.

There are a couple of things good to know.

## iOS

On the Simulator you could run into an issue where values do not get saved. To overcome this open the Entitlements.plist file and make sure that "Enable Keychain Access Groups" is checked. Also ensure that in Project->Options->iOS Bundle Signing, the Entitlements.plist is selected in Custom Entitlements for iPhoneSimulator platform.

## Android

You have to set a password when initialising, like this:
`SecureStorageImplementation.StoragePassword = "Your Password";`

This will be used to encrypt te settings. Make sure you keep it secret and do not change it.

## Windows

Same thing as Android, but now call `WinSecureStorageBase.StoragePassword = "Your password";`

If you have done this, you can now save any setting your like with:

`CrossSecureStorage.Current.SetValue(“SessionToken”, “1234567890”);`

Which can then be retrieved like this:

`var sessionToken = CrossSecureStorage.Current.GetValue (“SessionToken”);`

There are some more calls to delete a key and see if a key is present. Don't forget to install the NuGet package on both your shared code as well as your platform projects.